# How to stop previously running animation in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a game using cocos2d.

I'm moving sprites by applying the CCRepeatForever action in *ccTouchBegan* method and when the sprite collides with another sprite, the collision animation is at in *ccTouchMoved* method.I'm having trouble stopping the animation when the collision is over - I'm stopping it by using *stopAction* but it is not working.

This is the code I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    
    [selSprite resumeSchedulerAndActions];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];
    [self selectSpriteForTouch:touchLocation];   
    return TRUE;    
}

- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation 
{
    else if(selSprite==FuelTruck) 
    {
        NSMutableArray *FuelTruckWalkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = FuelTruckTouchStartFrameIndex; i <= FuelTruckTouchEndFrameIndex; ++i) {
            [FuelTruckWalkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftruck_move_%d.png", i]]];
        }
        FuelTruckWalkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:FuelTruckWalkAnimFrames delay:FuelTruckTouchFrameDelay];
        walkFuelTruck = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                            [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:FuelTruckWalkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:YES]];
        [selSprite runAction:walkFuelTruck]; 
    }
}

- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {    

    else if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selSprite.boundingBox,BluePlaneFuelHatch.boundingBox))
    { 
        NSMutableArray *FuelTruckAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = FuelTruckCollisionStartFrameIndex; i <= FuelTruckCollisionEndFrameIndex; ++i) 
        {
            [FuelTruckAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftruck_col_%d.png", i]]];
        }
        CCAnimation *FuelTruckAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:FuelTruckAnimFrames delay:FuelTruckCollisionFrameDelay];

        CCAction *FuelTruckCollisionBlue = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:FuelTruckAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

        [FuelTruck runAction:FuelTruckCollisionBlue];

        isCollided=YES;
    }
    else
    {

        if(isCollided==YES)
        { 
            isCollided=No;
            [FuelTruck stopAction:FuelTruckCollisionBlue];
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not stopping collision animation when collision is over. It takes few milliseconds to complete the animation why it is so?

Comment: I'm concerned you seem to have `if`s which start: `else if`. I can only assume you have left out some code.

Also please take the time to format your code, it just took me 5 minutes to realign everything. It may even help you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that your code won't compile, it seems to be a scope issue. Have a look at the comments I've added to this abridged version of your code.

```
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selSprite.boundingBox,BluePlaneFuelHatch.boundingBox))
    { //<(1)>
        ...
        //THIS ANIMATION IS ONLY AVAILABLE WITHIN THE BRACES MARKED WITH (1)
        CCAnimation *FuelTruckAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:FuelTruckAnimFrames delay:FuelTruckCollisionFrameDelay];

        CCAction *FuelTruckCollisionBlue = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:FuelTruckAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        ...
        isCollided=YES;
    }//<(1)>
    else
    {

        if(isCollided==YES)
        { 
            isCollided=No;
            //YOU ARE THEN TRYING TO USE THE VARIABLE HERE. IT DOESN'T EXIST IN THIS SCOPE.
            [FuelTruck stopAction:FuelTruckCollisionBlue];
        }
    }
```

Try this instead:

```
    //As a member variable
    CCAction *FuelTruckCollisionBlue;




    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(selSprite.boundingBox,BluePlaneFuelHatch.boundingBox))
    { //<(1)>
        ...
        //THIS ANIMATION IS ONLY AVAILABLE WITHIN THE BRACES MARKED WITH (1)
        CCAnimation *FuelTruckAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:FuelTruckAnimFrames delay:FuelTruckCollisionFrameDelay];

        FuelTruckCollisonBlue = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:FuelTruckAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];
        ...
        isCollided=YES;
    }//<(1)>
    else
    {

        if(isCollided==YES)
        { 
            isCollided=No;
            //YOU ARE THEN TRYING TO USE THE VARIABLE HERE. IT DOESN'T EXIST IN THIS SCOPE.
            [FuelTruck stopAction:FuelTruckCollisionBlue];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good advice but I would only +1 this if you show OP how to fix it (i.e. by declaring the `FuelTruckCollisionBlue` outside the `if` block) :)

Comment: As promised, +1 from me. But I just noticed after re-reading the code that it doesn't solve OP problem, simple because `if` and `else` are exclusive to one another, thus if the "true" block gets executed and sets `FuelTruckCollisonBlue`, the code won't get to the "false" block for the `stopAction` part, vice versa. What OP needs is adding `FuelTruckCollisonBlue` as a member variable instead of declaring it in that method.

Comment: I'm trying the code as suggested by James But still it's not stopping the animation. Please Help me to figure out this problem..

Comment: Did you provide all the necessary code? Try properly formatting your code with line indents and it should give you a better visual idea as to where your objects are scoped.